# How create postgres trigger in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, triggers, pg

I have a table product(id,name) and table product_raiting(product_id,rate_type,rate).
When I create new product, I need to create three raitings for this product.

How can I add postgres trigger with do something like:

```
    product.create
    product.product_raitings.create( :rate_type => 0, :rate => 0 )
    product.product_raitings.create( :rate_type => 1, :rate => 0 )
    product.product_raitings.create( :rate_type => 2, :rate => 0 )
    product.product_raitings.create( :rate_type => 3, :rate => 0 )
```

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want to create a trigger in the Database so on insert the DB does the work?

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html

```
CREATE FUNCTION addRaitings() RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO product_raitings(product_id,rate_type,rate) values(NEW.id,0,0);
      INSERT INTO product_raitings(product_id,rate_type,rate) values(NEW.id,1,0);
      INSERT INTO product_raitings(product_id,rate_type,rate) values(NEW.id,2,0);
      INSERT INTO product_raitings(product_id,rate_type,rate) values(NEW.id,3,0);
   END;
   ' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER createRaitingTrigger
        AFTER INSERT ON products
        FOR EACH ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE addRaitings();
```

or do you want rails to do the work?   then it would be an `after_create` callback 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

so perhaps something like this.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many product_raitings

  after_create :build_default_raitings

 private
 def build_default_raitings
    (0..3).each { |x| self.product_raitings.create(:rate_type => x, :rate => 0) }
 end
end
```